# How to do the the same thing recursively and still using Scanner and a Collection?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, collections, java.util.scanner

Here's the code I have created using the collection and the scanner parameters. I've been so confused to combine it into recursive, I used iteration.

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Deque deque = new LinkedList<>();

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your words (type R to reverse):");

    while(sc.hasNext()) {
      String line = sc.next();
      if(line.toLowerCase().equals("r")) {
        break;
      }
      deque.add(line);
    }

    System.out.println("\n===== Reversed Lines =====\n");        

    Iterator reverse = deque.descendingIterator();
    while (reverse.hasNext()) {
      System.out.println(reverse.next());
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, quick recap on **recursion**.

Every recursive method consists of **two parts**:

- **Base case** - that represents a simple edge-case (condition when recursion terminates) for which the outcome is known in advance.
- **Recursive case** - a part of a solution where *recursive calls* are made and where the main *logic* resides.

You can extract the code responsible for reading the **user input** into a separate method and substitute the `while` loop with the recursive call.

The **base case** is represented by two situations: `sc.hasNext()` yields `false` and user input is equal to `"r"`. Otherwise, the line will be added to queue and a new recursive call will be made.

And printing the content from the queue could be done recursively as well. The **base case** for this method is when `reverse.hasNext()` returns `false`. In the **recursive case** the next element will be printed, and a subsequent recursive call will be made.

So in order to be able to use `Scanner` and `Queue` you can either pass them as parameters or make them accessible globally.

Because of the requirements for this task, `Scanner` and `Queue` are declared locally inside the method `readAndPrint()` and as parameters of the method `readInput()`.

```
public class Main {

    public void readAndPrint() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Deque<String> deque = new LinkedList<>();
        System.out.println("Enter your words (type R to reverse):");
        readInput(sc, deque); // recursive helper-method that read from the console

        System.out.println("\n===== Reversed Lines =====\n");
        print(deque.descendingIterator()); // recursive helper-method that prints to the console
    }

    public static void print(Iterator<String> reverse) {
        if (!reverse.hasNext()) { // base case
            return;
        }

        System.out.println(reverse.next());
        print(reverse); // recursive call
    }

    public void readInput(Scanner sc, Deque<String> deque) {
        if (!sc.hasNext() && sc.hasNextLine()) { // no more input on this line, but there's at least one more line
            sc.nextLine(); // advance to the next line
        }
        if (!sc.hasNext()) { // base case
            return;
        }
        String line = sc.next();
        if (line.equalsIgnoreCase("r")) { // base case
            return;
        }
        deque.add(line);
        readInput(sc, deque); // recursive call
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ri.readAndPrint();
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Humpty Dumpty    // multyline input
sat on a wall R

===== Reversed Lines =====

wall
a
on
sat
Dumpty
Humpty
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242772/discussion-on-answer-by-alexander-ivanchenko-how-to-do-the-the-same-thing-recurs).